# MVVM RaisePropertyChanged in ViewModel or Model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

let's say I have a Server class with several properties (such as Ping) which are updated in the background.
I have a ServerViewModel which is holding the Server instance and a ServersViewModel which is holding the different instances of ServerViewModel in a ObservableCollection to display the servers in a List in the View.

The (shortened) Server Class:

```
public class Server: ObservableObject, IServer 
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IP adress of the server
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IPAddress IPAdress { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the server
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        private set
        {
            if(name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gives the string of the ip
    /// </summary>
    public string IP
    {
        get
        {
            return ip;
        }

        private set
        {
            if(ip != value)
            {
                ip = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IP");
            }                
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ping of the server
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Ping
    {
        get
        {
            return ping;
        }

        private set
        {
            if(ping != value)
            {
                ping = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Ping");
            }
        }
    }

    private Thread queryThread;

    private string name, ip;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the server instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ip">The ip adress or dns of the server</param>
    /// <param name="port">The common port to connect to</param>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Server(string ip, int port)
    {
        IP = ip;

        IPAddress tmpIP;

        // Check if the given IP matches a DNS
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out tmpIP))
        {
            try
            {
                this.IPAdress = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).AddressList[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.IPAdress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        }

        Port = port;

        queryThread = new Thread(QueryServer);
        queryThread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destructor for Server class. Stops the server thread running in background and cleans up.
    /// </summary>
    ~Server()
    {
        try
       {
            queryThread.Abort();
            queryThread = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignored
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the loop that is querying the server
    /// </summary>
    private void QueryServer()
    {
    }
}
```

As I'm updating the data in the background I added RaisePropertyChanged in the Proerties where it is needed.

The ServerViewModel:

```
public class ServerViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private Server server;

    public Server Server
    {
        get
        {
            return server;
        }
    }

    public ServerViewModel(Server server)
    {
        this.server = server;
    }
}
```

The ServersViewModel:

```
public class ServersViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    #region Members

    ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel> servers = new ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel>();

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public ObservableCollection<ServerViewModel> Servers
    {
        get
        {
            return servers;
        }

        set
        {
            servers = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Construction
    public ServersViewModel()
    {
        // Add servers to the collection
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I'm binding the ServersViewModel to a list in the view. My DataBinding for each item in the list looks like this:

```
<Label  Name="lblServerPing" Content="{Binding Server.Ping}" />
```

For me this looks wrong. Especially because I'm accessing the Server instance of the view and not a property of the view. I still don't know where to put the RaisePropertyChanged and how to fix this behaviour. I have to admit that it is working this way but I think it is not how it should look like in MVVM.

ObservableObject and ViewModelBase are from MVVM light and are implementing the needed interfaces.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the PropertyChanged event should be raised in the ViewModel, and the model should just be a collection of properties/objects.  The ViewModel would then expose those properties and notify the view when they change through the PropertyChanged event.

Here's a simplified version of what you're doing, which should hopefully paint a picture of where to go, IF you want to follow MVVM strictly, that is...

```
public class ServerModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
}

public class ServerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ServerModel model;

    public ServerViewModel(ServerModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public string Name
    {
         get { return model.Name; }
         private set
         {
              model.Name = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Name");
         }
    }

    public string IP
    {
         get { return model.IP; }
         private set
         {
              model.IP= value;
              OnPropertyChanged("IP");
         }
    }
}
```

The validation logic that you have inside the setters, would go in the ViewModel.  If logic inside the ViewModel becomes complex, it should ideally be outsourced to a service class - the ViewModels shouldn't contain a lot of complex logic, they simply tell the Views how to display the Model data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was the point I misunderstood in this concept. So I could move the background worker thread to the view model and let this thread refresh the server? That's how I would do in this case.